# C# Целочисленная прямоугольная матрица. Найти произведение 1й четверти и номер строки в которой все отрицательные

Tags: c#, матрицы

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста с заданием:

> Дана целочисленная прямоугольная матрица. Определить:
>
> 1. Произведение элементов, расположенных выше главной и побочной
>      диагонали.
> 2. Номер первой из строк, не содержащих ни одного положительного
>      элемента.

Знаю что 1-е находится через `(i < j) && (i + j < n + 1)`
Но как это всё грамотно записать и как показать матрицу в форме не знаю.
Ещё имеется такой код для создания матрицы:

```
int[,] a = new int[8, 8];
Random randomizer = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        a[i, j] = randomizer.Next(-9, 9);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно решить задачу таким образом:

```
/////////
int number;
for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    var isHavePositive = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        if (a[i, j] > 0)
        {
            isHavePositive = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isHavePositive)
    {
        number = i;
        break;
    }
}
//////////////


int result = 1;
int skiper = 1;
int ii = 0;
while (a.GetLength(1) > skiper * 2)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1) - 2 * skiper; j++)
    {
        result *= a[ii, j];
    }
    ii++;
    skiper++;
}
```

После этого number будет равен номеру строке без положительных элементов, а result произведению элементов над диагональями

Comment: Чёт он у меня не то считает...

Comment: тут подправил `if (a[i, j] >= 0)`  и чуть ниже `number = i + 1;`

Comment: спасибо за коррективы :)

Comment: с произведением ещё не разобрался) не то считает

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант:

```
textBox1.Clear();
int n = 6; //размерность
int[,] a = new int[n, n]; // создание массива
Random randomizer = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        a[i, j] = randomizer.Next(-5, 5);
        if (a[i, j] < 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text += (" " + a[i, j]);
        }
        else textBox1.Text += ("  " + a[i, j]);
    }
    textBox1.Text += (Environment.NewLine);
}
int number = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    var isHavePositive = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        if (a[i, j] >= 0)
        {
            isHavePositive = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isHavePositive)
    {
        number = i + 1;
        break;
    }
}
textBox2.Text = ("Номер строки в которой все элементы отрицательные : " + number) + (Environment.NewLine);
int x = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        if (i < j && i + j < n - 1)
            x *= a[i, j];
    }
}
textBox2.Text += ("Произведение элементов над диагоналями: " + x);
```